# Appending Text From A File To Text In Another File

Tags: bash, terminal, sh

I have two separate text files, one with 4 letter words and one with 4 digit numbers, all on individual lines.  The words in the on file correspond to the numbers on the same line in the other file.  For example:

CATS
RATS
HATS

matches up with

2287
7287
4287

What I would like is to append the numbers to the end of their matching word, so it looks like this:

CATS2287
RATS7287
HATS4287

so far what I have is this:

```
for i in $(cat numbers); do  
  sed 's/$/'$i'/' words;
done
```

but the problem is a) that doesn't print/echo out to a new file and b) it loops through each word every time the first loop comes to a new number so in the end, all the words are paired up with the last number in the number file.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paste -d "" /path/to/letters /path/to/numbers
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ paste -d "" CATS NUMS
CATS2287
RATS7287
HATS4287
```

Comment: @Tyler: there is a space between the `-d` and the double quotes `""`

Comment: thanks dude, paste was exactly what I was looking for.  I can't believe I spent so much time fussing around with sed and awk.  bash is an terrible, confusing language imo :\

Comment: @Tyler: it certainly can be at first, it definitely has its peculiarities.  Stick with it though as knowing shell programming is pretty invaluable IMHO.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer that best solved your problem. This helps you earn reputation as well as helps others with a similar question know where to look for a solution.  P.S. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

You can use the excellent little `paste(1)` utility:

```
$ cat a
CATS
RATS
HATS
$ cat b
2287
7287
4287
$ paste -d "" a b
CATS2287
RATS7287
HATS4287
$
```

`-d` specifies a list of delimiters; I gave it a blank list: no delimiters, no delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, my version of paste with `-d""` just results in numbers, the words get overwritten (GNU paste 8.10 on cygwin). my input files have no carriage returns.

```
paste words numbers | tr -d '\t'
```

Also, just with shell builtins

```
exec 3<words
exec 4<numbers
while read -u3 word; do
  read -u4 num
  echo $word$num
done
exec 3<&-
exec 4<&-
```

Comment: it's `-d ""` with a space, not `-d""`

Comment: @SiegeX, ah, interesting. Wonder if that's a bug

Comment: Oh, I get it now. With `paste -d"" words numbers` (no space before the "") paste is taking the word "words" as the delimiter list. So it is only pasting one file, "numbers".

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X:

```
paste -d "\0" <(echo abc) <(echo def)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to do that

Paste:

```
paste -d "" file1 file2
```

awk

```
awk '{ getline f<"file2" ; print $0f}' file1
```

Bash:

```
exec 6<"file2"
while read -r line
do
    read -r S <&6
    printf "${line}${S}\n"
done <"file1"
exec >&6-
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{f=File.open("file1")};print $_.chomp+f.readline;END{f.close}' file
```